# hide inner div when outer class css display is table important

Tags: jquery, css

Given an outer div whose css class contains `display:table !important` , its inner div still shows when you `.hide()` the outer div with jQuery, or set the outer divs inline style to `display:none;`

Is this what they mean by 'cascading' style sheets? ;)

I am really surprised I have not run into this before. Can someone explain the mechanism of this conflict and what I should do given I do not want to mess with `display:table !important` in the css class.

Right now I am looking at this with Mozilla.

http://jsfiddle.net/YrEEk/1/

Comment: It's not just the inner div that still shows, it's all of the outer div's content: http://jsfiddle.net/YrEEk/2/. (The hide works if you remove the class at the same time as you hide: http://jsfiddle.net/YrEEk/3/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`!important` rules override other style rules, (even inline ones), which is why you should use specificity to determine precedence in your stylesheets instead of throwing in an `!important`.

The only way to override that `!important` rule now is to use another `!important` rule, one that occurs lower in the cascade or is more specific.

```
.hidden{
    display:none !important;
}
```

Now you can apply this class to the element:

```
$('#d1').addClass('hidden');
```

Here is a demonstration: http://jsfiddle.net/YrEEk/4/

Comment: Thanks, for some reason I was suffering under the delusion that inline styles were given priority over important.

Answer (score 2):

That's because when you use !important, setting anything else after it without !important will not work as it is still overridden by the initial "display:table !important"

```
$('#d1').hide();
```

This line simply adds a css property "display:none" to the element which does not work dcause you still have "display:table !important"

If you want, just set CSS as "display:table" without the !important.